# Ping on port number to test server socket accept function

Tags: java, linux, sockets

I have written a Java program in linux. Which is running as foreground service. This service is listening to port number 7777. I want test if it is actually listening to it or not.

I am looking for a command in Linux, which will help me check if the ServerScoket.accept(); is  actually working or not?

Thanks in advance
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: you can use either `netstat` for listing or `telnet` or `nc`

Answer (score 1):

Somebody at Google Plus, just replied. The command is

telnet [hostname] [port]﻿

Answer (score 1):

As its name points it `netstat` (network status) for me is the best tool to check a network status.

You can use:

```
netstat -nab
```

And if you service is listening on an specific port you should see this output for your port:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address        (state)        rxbytes    txbytes
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.51766        127.0.0.1.12080        ESTABLISHED       4244          0
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.10000        *.*                    LISTEN               0          0
```

You can find useful `netstat` examples here:

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/58e72888-6340-46ac-b488-d31aa4058e9c/entry/linux_netstat_command_explained_with_10_examples?lang=en

By the way, there is an excellent command named `netcat` that you can use to test connections. You can take a [look at it here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/nc.htm). A simple usage to connect is:

```
nc host.example.com 1234
```

Or as you said, you can use telnet too as:

```
telnet host.example.com 1234
```

Comment: `netstat` tells you the state of the listening port(s), from which you could draw assumptions, it however does **not** test the `accept()`.